# github not accepting private SSH Key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, github, private-key, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Private ED25519 SSH key, on a Windows system (using WSL). Permissions of the private key are `400` and permissions on the Public Key are `444`. When I test my connection, using `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` this is the response I get.

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:uO4IMeDU10K+ME5e2LPI/9dIvPu1tAefz2wx60I+AIA explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

I've ran the `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` to show the fingerprint as well I ran the `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` and can confirm that the fingerprint matches. For me this indicates that the keys should match each other (please correct me if I am wrong on this assumption), but it seems as if that `type 51` means the user is unauthenticated. I can also confirm the public key has been uploaded into my github account, as well I can confirm I'm added the following:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

into my `~/.bashrc` file. I'm pretty confused as why this isn't working. If anyone has any suggestions I would love to get someone else's input.